# Adding a Countdown Timer to Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, timer

I’m making an iOS app with a Node/Express/Mongo backend.

It looks for people in a close proximity (about 100 ft around) and puts those user objects in an array - [currentUsersAround]

Once those users leave the 100ft radius, they get put into a different array - [passedByUsers]

I want to set a timer in the backend for each user object in passedByUsers for a span of 2 hours and once it counts down it would splice itself out of the array.

There’s a lot of code for the entire thing but in terms of adding a timer to each user I have:

```
for (i = 0; i < passedByUsers.length; i++) {
  passedByUsers[i].timer = setTimeout(function() {
    passedByUsers.splice(passedByUsers.indexOf(this), 1)
  }, 7200000)
}
```

I was thinking about incorporating both Date.now() and setTimeOut and also I could set a passedByUsers array inside each user object with a Date.now().
I'm just wondering if there was a better way.
Thank you.

Comment: i would do that: add lastSeen with a time to user object in passedByUsers, and check the array in every 1 minute and clean up what is outdated

Comment: Hm, ok. that makes sense. Thank you.